# How can I turn off clickable links in markdown mode?

Tags: markdown-mode

I would like `markdown-mode` to treat URLs as normal text, so that I can click on them to place the cursor inside them rather than loading the page in a browser.

I tried toggling `goto-address-mode`, which didn't help, and I tried removing *http* and *https* from the list of *Markdown Uri Types*.  I tried a few other things that in retrospect don't make much sense; I looked through all the variables that began with `markdown-` and couldn't find any that applied.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `C-h v mouse-1-click-follows-link` to learn the default behavior, and how to change it if you want to.

Comment: This comment is the answer. Please promote to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can place the cursor in the middle of a clickable element by doing a "long click" (i.e. press, hold for more than 0.5s, and then release).

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is editing hidden links (see the link text and not the address):

The easy "built-in"  **(keyboard / not mouse)** solution for editing the link, will be to move your cursor to it  (using the keyboard) and type `M-x markdown-toggle-url-hiding`, then you can edit the address as text.
Have a look at [Github issue](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/199)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it off.

Use <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `mouse-1-click-follows-link` to learn and change the default behaviour.

Comment: This answer is based on the excellent comment from @xuchunyang. While this comment was the correct answer. It was a comment, and the author did not promote it to an answer.